# custom format specifications in python

Tags: python, format, specifications

in python, how can a custom format-specification be added, to a class ? for example, if i write a matrix class, i would like to 
define a '%M' (or some such) which would then dump the entire contents of the matrix...

thanks

Comment: Show us an example on how you are envisioning to use %M with your matrix class?

Comment: The usual solution is to use "%s" in the format and override the class `__str__`.  Why not do this simple thing that everyone else does?

Answer (score 5):

Defining the `__str__()`/`__unicode__()` and/or `__repr__()` methods will let you use the existing `%s` and `%r` format specifiers as you like.

Comment: yes i know. i want to define something different. basically something similar to variadic C functions...

Comment: @anupam: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_Python

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that it's possible to define a new format specifier for print.  You might be able to add a method to your class that sets a format that you use, and define the **str** method of the class to adjust it's output according to how it was set. Then the main print statement would still use a '%s' specifier, and call your custom **str**.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use custom specifiers you cannot do this in way that compatible with the rest of the Python language and standard library. **Take advantage of what Python already supplies (`%s` and `%r`) and customise it for your needs by overriding `__str__()` or `__repr__()`**

```
class Matrix(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return convert_to_pretty_matrix_string(self)
    def __repr__(self):
        return convert_to_textual_matrix_format(self)
```